# align items next to each using bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, components

i have this images

[image: images]

i have loaded them from api and i created another component that will print them. my problem is that i have about 50 images and i want each 3 to be on one row with the title under them and the next one will hold 3 new but i don't really know bootstrap and can't seem to solve this problem.

postItem.js

```
import React from 'react';

function PostItem ({key,src,thumbnailUrl,onClick,title}) {
    return (
    <div>
            <div key={key}>
                    <img src={src} thumbnailUrl={thumbnailUrl} onClick={onClick}></img>
                        <div>{title}</div>    
                </div>
    </div>
    )}

export default PostItem;
```

post.js:

```
<div><h3>Posts</h3></div>
            <div>
            <div>{newPhotosLocally.map(picture => 
                 <PostItem 
                 key={picture.id}
                 src={picture.thumbnailUrl} 
                 thumbnailUrl={picture.thumbnailUrl} 
                 onClick={() => showPicture(picture.url,picture.id)}
                 title={picture.title}/>
                //  <div key={picture.id}>
                //     <img src={picture.thumbnailUrl} thumbnailUrl={picture.thumbnailUrl} onClick={() => showPicture(picture.url,picture.id)}></img>
                //         <div>{picture.title}</div>    
                // </div>
            )}</div>
            </div>
```

Comment: If i am not wrong you want this behaviour for each row?  https://ibb.co/LktfwkH

Comment: yessss exactlyy

Comment: have you already included bootstrap in your project?

Comment: yes i did but what is the code you've used to do this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you have already included `bootstrap` in your project, you can use `col` class to specify the width for each image.

You can read about grid system of bootstrap here: [GRID SYSTEM](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)

Your `postItem.js` file should look like this:

```
import React from 'react';

function PostItem ({key,src,thumbnailUrl,onClick,title}) {
return (
  <div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-4"  key={key}>
        <img src={src} thumbnailUrl={thumbnailUrl} onClick={onClick}></img>
        <div>{title}</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4" key={key}>
        <img src={src} thumbnailUrl={thumbnailUrl} onClick={onClick}></img>
        <div>{title}</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4" key={key}>
        <img src={src} thumbnailUrl={thumbnailUrl} onClick={onClick}></img>
        <div>{title}</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
)}
```